# Is JTextArea the right class for my purpose?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want to create a text area where the user inputs some text, presses enter and that text is sent to a class that does something with it ( changes the order of the words for example ), then the editted text is displayed on the next line in the text area.

Furthermore, if the user writes something on the line after the first editted text and again presses enter - only that last line is sent to the editting class. The user should be able to edit all the lines as well, if he wants to. Something like the text area in Wolfram Mathematica, if people know it.

I am new to Java and I have no idea whether I have to use JTextArea and design somekind of a class myself that will do this or there is already something that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

With a JTextArea this is possible, but I would create a new Class, wich extends JTextArea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with JTextArea.  I wouldn't extend it as previously suggested, but I would add a KeyListener and implement the specific methods you're interested in.  For instance, you're interested in when Enter is typed; so you may do something like this:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
  //look for the ENTER key and perform specific processing
  int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
  switch(keyCode) { 
    case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
      //do stuff
    break;
  }
}
```